# How do you link two nodes together as parent child in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a set of nodes which are part of a hierarchy. One node can be related to other node by virtue of child having a parentKey which links to another node. In relational land this would be represented as a 'pigs ear' in an ER diagram.

How can I can generate this relationship between the nodes in neo4j?

I'm quite new to graphs so apologies if I haven't explain it very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to link a "child" node to a "parent" node. That is very easy to do. For instance:

```
CREATE (child:Person)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(parent:Person)
```

In this sample data model, we have a `Person` node label, and a `HAS_PARENT` relationship type. `HAS_PARENT` relationships are used to link `Person` nodes to represent the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about already existing nodes, you can match the existing nodes and then use merge to create a relationship.

```
MATCH (child:SomeLabel) MATCH (parent:SomeOtherLabel)
MERGE (parent)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(child)
```

You can also use merge when creating new nodes.

See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html

Comment: Hi ! That link was useful. I put this together MATCH (parent:NODE)
MERGE (child:NODE {parentkey:parent.key})
create (parent)-[r:PARENT_OF]->(child)
//RETURN parent.key, child.parentkey, so NODE is the same node, not joining two different nodes together. The keys are int. I don't get any joins? weird . . .